# Execute Ruby Worker Script in Rails Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon

I have the following case:

I want to be able to run an independent Ruby script as a daemon.  I would like to be able to execute this script in the context/environment of my Rails project (so that the script can have access to the back-end/my Rails models, for example).

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner).

You could also create a rake task.

Comment: Thanks for the response, forgot to mark answer as accepted...  rails runner is working great for me.